# Gradle sync failed: Unable to start the daemon process with no specific main class defined

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm using android studio 3.2.1 and seeing this error

```
Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/3.3/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Please read the following process output to find out more:
-----------------------
Error: Could not find or load main class =
```

This started happening all of a sudden and I don't know what changed and how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is related with your **jvmargs** on your gradle properties file.

> For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used

You can try the following:

1. Open your **gradle.properties**
2. Add the following:

   org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

(it can be more, depends on your machine memory capacity).

3. Save the file, reboot project

—-

From the [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html):

> **org.gradle.jvmargs=(JVM arguments)** 
>   Specifies the JVM arguments used
>   for the Gradle Daemon. The setting is particularly useful for
>   configuring JVM memory settings for build performance.

Comment: Man, you're a savior!